# In java, reading file using inputstream after deleting the file

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have a question regarding reading files in java.
Here is the sample code

```
File path = new File("myfile.txt");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
file.delete();                
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

I create an input stream and try to read it. As they say, its like a pipe, you read values byte by byte.
To speed it up, we can use BufferedReader which can read chunk by chunk.
So, I delete this file before reading.
Now, when i read it, it still reads complete file, even though file is not there.
If inputStream is a pipe, why is it not failing ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You are not reacting on the returned `boolean` from the `delete` call. Most probably, it is `false`, indicating that the file was not deleted. The reason - most probably - is that by opening an input stream from that file you are still holding a handle to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because the txt file you are loading from is so small it is fully read on initialization of the buffered reader.

Comment: yes this is most likely the issue, to confirm i would get a large text file from online or create it yourself and then test it again.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the file still exists in the reader and the inputStream. Deleting the source file won't change anything until you rerun your application. 
BufferedReader and InputStream classes are probaly prepared for similar situations like this. It can be useful if the source of the file goes offline during the run. 
Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not a professional programmer.